# Big / Small Letters in AutoComplete Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, str-replace

Search term only show its own size, for example;

If the search word is only showing small case letters

[image]

How do I make the big and small differences are unimportant?

```
$Text= str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b style="color: #df5a5a;text-decoration: underline;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['Text']);
$TextDesc= str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b style="color: #df5a5a;text-decoration: underline;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['TextDesc']);
```

Comment: convert both the searched text and searched items to upper or lower case. Seems that you searched items are lowercase already so you can just convert whatever user inputs into lowercase too.

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf I can change upper to lowercase or lowercase to upper but I have no idea mixed word

Comment: you are only changing them when you do the search. Basically, store the strings in a different variable where they are upper cased or lower cased then do the comparison but for the UI, display the original strings. Don't know how much of a performance hit this will do but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is the prototype,and hope you know how to query the database and convert them to a JSON format
http://code.runnable.com/V9Qu6iYUrhNC267j/big-small-letters-in-autocomplete-search-for-php

Comment: I mentioned this is not me